# How to find the maximum element in a column in a matrix and display the index(row number of the maximum element)?

Tags: arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have a matrix of M rows and N columns. How do I find the maximum element in each column and display the index(i.e., the row number of the Maximum element)?

Ex: (Considering a 2x2 matrix)
Input:

1 5

2 4

Current Output:  2 5

Required Output: 2 1 (display of index positions)

Currently I am able to only display the maximum element in each column by creating a function and then calling it in the Main function.

```
**The Function to find and display the Maximum element in each column:**
public static void MaxColumn(int cols, int rows,
                                        int[,] matrix)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
            {
                int max = matrix[0, i];
                for (int j = 1; j < rows; j++)
                {
                    if (matrix[j, i] > max)
                        max = matrix[j, i];
                }

                Console.Write(maxm + " ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Question: Would this be a generic matrix or a fixed one? What would happen if the max value appears in two different positions in the array?

Comment: Here, we are trying to find the index of the max value in each column and display. If the max value repeats in the column, we consider the index of the first one.